# Taking an large output and turning it into a var in linux

Tags: linux

If I do something like `od -b text`
that would then output something like `02467324 14731245 37263153`
How would you turn each number into a variable.
Eg.
`A = 0`
`B = 2`
`C = 4`
`D = 6`

Comment: Iterate over each number (in advanced shells with a parameter expansion for string-indexing storing each number as an element in an array), or in POSIX shell, separate the digits with `sed` and loop over the characters. It isn't immediately apparent that you could save the digits to individual variables in POSIX shell. In advanced shells, the array provides a way for you to store in reference each digit as a separate element of the array.

Comment: Just a funny remark, showing a weakness in your idea: you have in your example 32 digits, you want all of them to put into a variable, called by a letter of the alphabet but the alphabet only contains 26 letters :-) As proposed by David, an array is more suited for this.